# SSH asks for password

Tags: ssh, password

I have already :

- Installed the server
- Generated the pub/pri keys with -P ""
- Copied the id_rsa.pub to authorized_keys
- ssh localhost > answered "yes", copied to known_hosts
- tried ssh localhost  >> still asks for password

Output:

```
hduser@hduser1-desktop:~$ ssh -v localhost
OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7, OpenSSL 0.9.8k 25 Mar 2009
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to localhost [127.0.0.1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/hduser/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /home/hduser/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: Checking blacklist file /usr/share/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: Checking blacklist file /etc/ssh/blacklist.RSA-2048
debug1: identity file /home/hduser/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-
3ubuntu7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3p1 Debian-3ubuntu7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<1024<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/hduser/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering public key: /home/hduser/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Trying private key: /home/hduser/.ssh/identity
debug1: Trying private key: /home/hduser/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Try using `ssh-copy-id`. You may have permission issues. This program sets the proper permissions.

Comment: its localhost so shouldn't it resolve such issues ?

Comment: Issue resolved: chmod g-w homedirectory . This is a weird prob or bug in my opinion. Thx

Comment: @user1435470: not a bug at all. It's a security precaution by `sshd` so that only you (and `root`) can amend the file with allowed keys. The permissions on `~/.ssh` also matter, btw.

Comment: setting home and .ssh permissions to 750 don't fix this for me. I still can't "ssh localhost" without being asked for a password. I'd really like to so that I can use a Fabric script which configures servers to set up my local dev/test environment.

Comment: The answer did not help me: http://askubuntu.com/questions/628188/ssh-keeps-asking-for-a-password

Answer (score 1):

Check the permissions and ownership of the file /home/hduser/.ssh/authorized_keys

It should be `-rw------- hduser hduser`

If not, you can fix this with

```
chown hduser:hduser ~hduser/.ssh/authorized_keys
chmod 0600 ~hduser/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Then try to connect to your localhost with

```
ssh -i /home/hduser/.ssh/id_rsa hduser@localhost
```

If it still doesn't work, check your recent auth logs in your favourite way,

```
sudo tail /var/log/auth.log
sudo cat /var/log/auth.log
sudo less /var/log/auth.log
sudo grep "Authentication refused" /var/log/auth.log
...
```

Look for something like this and google the error message you get

```
Jan 21 09:03:11 hduser sshd[29543]: Authentication refused: ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure in your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` you have the following settings:

`PubkeyAuthentication yes`

`ChallengeResponseAuthentication no`

`UsePAM yes`

`AllowUsers YOUR_USER_NAME`

Comment: This did not help me: http://askubuntu.com/questions/628188/ssh-keeps-asking-for-a-password