# ssh keeps asking for a password

Tags: ssh, password, cluster, mpi

I am trying to set up an MPI cluster, following [Setting Up an MPICH2 Cluster in Ubuntu](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MpichCluster) tutorial.

At the end of step *7*, it says that I should not receive a password request, which unfortunately is not the case.

```
gsamaras@pythagoras:~$ ssh geomcomp.com hostname
gsamaras@geomcomp's password:
```

I have edited `~/.bashrc` as instructed from the tutorial.

Comment: whats the permission of the file `authorized_keys` ?

Comment: Check with `ssh -vvv`

Comment: @heemayl I edited my post with the requested information.

Comment: Permissions on .ssh and authorized_keys should be 600. Look into sshd logs on the server, you'll probably find it complaining about something like "... file is world readable ...".

Comment: @Fiisch I admit I do not know how to look at them. Should I change them like the 3rd answer in the linked question?

Comment: yes, thats it, `chmod 600 ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` should do the trick

Comment: Did that @Fiisch, stills asks for a password!

Comment: Is your home directory on `pythagoras` the same as on `geomcomp.di.uoa.gr`? The guide assumes you are running the commands from a cluster node and that your home directory is mounted on all nodes with NFS.

Comment: @lgpasquale they are like this: `gsamaras@pythagoras` and `gsamaras@geomcomp`, but I am not sure if you are asking this. When, I have done all the steps of the guide (1-6) until this point, thus it should be mounted, ***I guess***. What I should do?

Comment: ok, probably better check the sshd log on the server. on ubuntu it should go into `/var/log/secure` or `/var/log/auth.log`

Comment: OK I got it, but it is big. What part should I post in your opinion @Fiisch? Maybe only the last session?

Comment: Is pythagoras one of the nodes? The guide tells you to mount `/mirror` on all nodes and to use that as the home directory for your user. From your logs I see that your home directory on pithagoras is `/home/gsamaras`. What's your home directory on geomcomp? Is it the same directory you mounted in step 4 of the guide?

Comment: your failed connection attempts - there should be something with your username mentioned.
the best way is to fire-up second terminal and watching the logfile while you connect to the server

Comment: @lgpasquale yes, I did the `/mirror` part. Pythagoras is supposed to be the master node and geomcomp the slave. `gsamaras@geomcomp:~$ pwd
/home/gsamaras`. Is this OK? Thanks Fiisch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guide assumes that you are using `/mirror` as your home directory on all cluster nodes (as well as on the master node, which is `ub0` for the guide and `pythagoras` for you).

If you are not using `/mirror` as your home directory (or, more precisely, if your home directory is not shared among all nodes), the following line:

```
mpiu@ub0:~/.ssh$ cat id_rsa.pub >> authorized_keys
```

will simply add your key to the list of authorized keys on `ub0` (i.e. on `pythagoras`).

If your home directory is not shared among nodes, you need to add your public key to the `authorized_keys` file on each node.

One way of doing this is to use `ssh-copy-id`:

```
ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub gsamaras@geomcomp.com
```

and similarly for all other nodes

*Note:* At the beginning of step 7, the guide assumes you are creating a user named `mpiu` on all nodes, whose home directory is `/mirror`. It doesn't, however, tell you how to do so.

Comment: Damn, I want to follow the guide closely. I did a `cd /mirror` and it hanged up. `mpiu` did not work for me, because it said that the name did not exist, thus I used mine, `gsamaras`.

Comment: If I also do only the root, I get the same `gsamaras@pythagoras:~$ cd /
gsamaras@pythagoras:/$ ls
hangs up`

Comment: Probably I should ask a new question for the `/mirror`, because, even though I remember creating it, I can't acess it. Shouldn't I be able to access it?

Comment: If you created `/mirror` on pythagoras, then you should be able to access it at least from there. If you can't, then check its permissions (`ls -la /mirror`). Once you can access it correctly from there you should see if it's mounted correctly on the other nodes (see if it appears in the output of `gsamaras@geomcomp:~$ sudo mount`)

Comment: Can't do that either. Asked a new question here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/628419/cd-mirror-freezes and then hopefully, I can get back here and I hope, accept your answer.

Comment: The question about `/mirror` seems to have no luck. :/ `sudo mount` in geomcomp does not list `/mirror`.

Comment: Should I skip that part of `/mirror`?

Comment: Not having `/mirror` should not prevent you from logging in with your ssh key. Make sure your key appears in the `authorized_keys` file on `geomcomp`.

Comment: This also helped: http://serverfault.com/questions/139156/ssh-agent-admitted-failure-to-sign-using-the-key